# "Error in BLang parser rest service for composer" when run the composer

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

When I'm run the composer using CMD. Composer run properly.But this error appears in the console.

```
C:\>composer
2017-07-07 23:09:05,446 INFO  - Ballerina Composer URL: http://localhost:9091
2017-07-07 23:09:35,164 ERROR - Error in BLang parser rest service for composer
```

Can anyone explain why this happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the current release and this won't break the composer functionality. We are tracking this issue at the moment and will be fixed in our next release v0.90. Please follow [link](https://github.com/ballerinalang/composer/issues/1028) for updates.